# Do named arguments replace the builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, builder-pattern

When using a language that supports named and optional arguments, does the builder pattern no longer have a practical use?

**Builder:**

```cs
new Builder(requiredA, requiredB).setOptionalA("optional").Build();
```

**Optional/named arguments:**

```cs
new Object(requiredA, requiredB, optionalA: "optional");
```

Comment: How do you handle 20 optional arguments? There isn't a problem the Builder needs to solve until it gets large. At the point you've described here you've got two constructors (and I wouldn't build a Builder for that small of a problem).

Comment: Even with optional arguments - if the constructor has more than 2 arguments, I favour using a value object to encapsulate configuration. The same goes for fluid inerfaces and builder: Anything greater than 3 would be substituted by a value object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Builders are most useful when your object needs a *lot* of arguments/dependencies to be useful, or you want to allow many different ways of constructing the object.

Off the top of my head, I can imagine someone might want to "build" objects in a 3D game like this:

```cs
// Just ignore the fact that this hypothetical god class is coupled to everything ever
new ObjectBuilder(x, y, z).importBlenderMesh("./meshes/foo")
                          .syncWithOtherPlayers(serverIP)
                          .compileShaders("./shaders/foo.vert", "./shaders/foo.frag")
                          .makeDestructibleRigidBody(health, weight)
                          ...
```

I would argue this example is more readable with the builder methods I made up just now than it would be with optional parameters:

```cs
new Object(x, y, z, meshType: MESH.BLENDER,
                    meshPath: "./meshes/foo",
                    serverToSyncWith: serverIP,
                    vertexShader: "./shaders/foo.vert",
                    physicsType: PHYSICS_ENGINE.RIGID_DESTRUCTIBLE,
                    health: health,
                    weight: weight)
                    ...
```

In particular, the information implied by the builder method names has to get replaced by yet more parameters, and it's much easier to forget about one parameter in a group of closely related parameters. In fact, the fragment shader is missing, but you wouldn't notice that unless you knew to look for it.

---

Of course, if your object only takes one to five arguments to construct, there's no need to get the builder pattern involved, whether or not you have named/optional parameters.

Comment: I don't buy your arguments.  If the builder method names are so wonderful, you can use them as well for the parameter names.  If parameters are closely related, put them into a small object constructor.

Comment: @user949300 I think you've missed the important part of the point, which is that the builder methods here describe relationships between the parameters that get lost if you just have a bunch of optional parameters. In Ixrec's builder example, "health" and "weight" are clearly logically part of the destructible body settings, but that relationship get l gets lost in the optional argument version.

Comment: not if one of the optional parameters is (body: new DestructibleRigidBody(health, weight), ...)

Comment: @Jules. What Weyland said - make a little well-named constructor for weight & height.

Comment: @WeylandYutani: And you think that nesting constructor calls in each other is somehow more readable than a method chain? I think people are losing track here of the difference between what is possible and what is nicer to use.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what Ixrec said, the constructors or method named parameters won't allow you to have your object in a to-be-constructed state in which it can still be modified before building it. This is the beauty of the Builder, where you can delegate parts of its construction to different methods or classes altgether:

```
var myThingBuilder = new ThingBuilder("table");
myThingBuilder.setAttribute(Attributes.Legs, 4);

inventoryManager.setPrices(myThingBuilder);

// inventory manager
var availableCheapestMaterial = getMaterial();
myThingBuilder.setMaterial(availableCheapestMaterial);
```

Basically, you're also able to throw your builder around your system until it is ready to build the final object, allowing you to decrease the amount of knowledge that your builder-consumer needs to have.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph.  If you "throw your builder around the system until it is ready", it has **far too much** knowledge of the system.  Your ThingBuilder knows about Attributes, is mysteriously modified by InventoryManager, and knows about Materials.  Don't see how that is decreasing knowledge.

Comment: @user949300 Think of how it would be _without_ the builder traveling across the system. You'd be forced to have a class with a huge fan-out factor, and that is just necessary to build the Thing. (Of course, assuming your class doesn't concentrate all the knowledge, this is what we wanted to avoid in the first place.) Now, if this class has any other responsibility, you're creating a huge class, breaking S in SOLID. If that's the only responsibility, you're making yourself a ThingBuilder.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you are doing with the builder.

If you use builder just to set (and vary) object properties and (defer) object creation, it can be replaced with named params (if available for the language).

Replacing the builder, you may have the readability/usage tradeoff that @Ixrec mentioned (or may not have it, it depends on what you are doing with the builder).

However, if your builder does more than just holding the properties and each construction step involves logic, it can't be replaced.

[MockBuilder](https://paddycorry.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/fluent-java-apis-ii-the-mockbuilder-pattern/) is an example where it can't be replaced with named params. From the page:

[image: Logic on creation steps cannot be replaced with named params]

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, updated answer.

Answer (score -5):

The builder pattern is essential when working with immutable objects. There are a lot of benefits working with immutable objects, especially in making your program be more robust executing in a concurrent environment (i.e., threads)

Comment: Yes, Builders are great for working with complex immutable objects (or even mutable ones - you need to make sure that the object is in a consistent state before it can be used).  That said, `new Integer(42)`, `new BigDecimal("42.000")` and `new String("foobar")` are all constructors to immutables that... well, a builder would be needlessly complex for these instances. So a builder isn't *essential* for working with immutable when constructors can work just as well.

Comment: Yes, a constructor can be used with immutable objects, that is not being denied. But the original question was whether the Builder pattern has any practical use apart from the optional arguments and my response was to clarify this.

Comment: The original question says *nothing* about immutable objects. It is asking about named parameters and the relationship to them with Builders. Your answer is about the builder and its relationship to immutable objects. I have a hard time seeing how your answer answers the question.